# Создание шаблонов для wordpress, Joomla , drupal  etc

Tags: drupal, joomla, wordpress

Добрый вечер ребята, у меня такой вопрос, я конечно понимаю что лучше всего делать все своими руками, особенно верстку по картинке и т.д. , но может кто-то из Вас, дизайнеров пользуется такой программой как Artisteer? Есть ли спрос на эту программу у работодателя, или все же нужно самому в блокноте создавать все с 0? 
Заранее спасибо ;)

Answer (score 1):

Добрый вечер! Из личного опыта- не советую использовать Artisteer. Шаблоны хоть и красивые, но на деле "корявые"; проблемы с кроссбраузерностью; если заказчик попросит что-то поменять - в коде черт ноги переломает. Лучше писать свой код. Не обязательно использовать блокнот, есть много других прекрасных программ(интегрированных сред разработки) с автодополнением - набросать шаблон можно за 15 минут.

Comment: спасибо, я так и догадалась уже)